# Retrieve URI Before the Binding of Parameters

Tags: php, slim, middleware, slim-3

In my Slim Framework 3 router I have the following route: `/account/{username}`

In my middleware, when I retrieve the request URI it'll look something like `/account/jordan`. Is it possible in my middleware to retrieve the URI string before the binding of the username parameter?

In my middleware I'd like to retrieve the string that I've defined in my routes: `/account/{username}`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The arguments from the route are available in the `routeInfo` which is a request-attribute, you can use it with

```
$routeInfo = $request->getAttributes('routeInfo');
$args = $routeInfo[2];
$username = $args['username'];
```

The `routeInfo` is only available when you enable the setting `determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware` like this:

```
$settings = ['determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true];
$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => $settings]);
```

Comment: I want the string literal `/account/{username}` without the binding of parameters, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find all informations about the route in the `route` attribute of the $request object. The `determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware` setting must be set to `true`.

```
$route = $request->getAttribute('route');

// do something with that information
$name = $route->getName();
$groups = $route->getGroups();
$methods = $route->getMethods();
$arguments = $route->getArguments();
```